# Restrict future Apple Watch apps to capable devices only

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'd like to restrict the sales of my next app to devices that are able to control an Apple Watch (iPhone 5 at least).

I can't find (in the doc or on Internet) which value for UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities I should put in the info.plist file.

Comment: If you are wanting to do this because you want the app to only be used with the watch, be aware that my understanding is that apps with watch extensions need to also provide useful functionality in their own right, and cannot be solely the code backend for a watch app.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently API for knowing whether a device is paired with Apple Watch.

Even simply from an iOS app review perspective, if a user downloads an app onto their iPhone that app is expected to provide value regardless of any external products.

See [Apple's App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API.

As you are also no doubt aware, requiring iOS 9 will also not assist you as it runs on iPhone 4S. While it is speculation, it is possible that this will de facto change if iOS 10 is released in September/October 2016, as expected, as that may remove support for older iPhones that cannot be paired with an Apple Watch (for mostly reasons of performance, unrelated to Apple Watch capability).

However, if you are wanting to do this because you want the app to only be used with the watch, be aware that App Store review requires that apps with WatchKit extensions need to also provide useful functionality in their own right, and cannot be solely the code backend for a watch app. Therefore, you would be expected to provide functionality to users who do not (and even cannot) attach an Apple Watch to their phones.